# javascript string concatenation

Tags: php, javascript, string

I know that in php you can do

```
abc = 'some';

abc .= 'thing';

echo abc; will output : something
```

how to do that in javascript ?

i have try abc = abc + bcd... but there should be a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
abc = 'some';

abc += 'thing';

alert(abc);  // will output `something`
```