# Javascript: Is there a syntax like this

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656484/javascript-string-concatenation)

In php we can add string in a string variable with this syntax

```
$string += 'foo';
```

In javascript, will this syntax above is accepted.

```
var strFoo;
strFoo += ' another Foo.';
```

Please help me with this simple question.

Comment: Did you try it? http://jsfiddle.net/3Wmux/ works as expected (since `strFoo` is not initialised with any value, you get `undefined`. Or http://jsfiddle.net/3Wmux/1/ with an empty string as initial value).

Comment: If you realize that this is a simple question, you should be able to simply test it. Try your browser console or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here, I made the test page for you. http://jsfiddle.net/PpaeB/

Comment: @FelixKling yes, $string += "foo"; will not work in PHP, because that's for integers I believe, not for string concatination.

Comment: Where does undefined from?

Comment: @user1441797: You declare the variable like `var strFoo;`, but do not give it an initial value, so it takes on the value `undefined`. Initialize it to the empty string if you don't want that.

Comment: @kennypu: I'm talking about JavaScript, since the question is about JavaScript.

Comment: @user1441797: As I said, since you don't explicitly assign a value to `strFoo`, it will have the initial value of `undefined`. Then you say to JavaScript to treat that value as a string (because you concatenate it with `"another foo."`). The default string representation of `undefined` is simply the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: @FelixKling oh, i see now, you're asking if he tried it, I thought you were asking me.

Comment: @kennypu: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding... :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, JavaScript supports [augmented assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment), including the `+=` operator.